# get results of numpy sub arrays in seperate sub-arrays on performing an operation, without using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

The below code checks if each element of sub-arrays is greater than 2 and gives the result in their respective sub-arrays:

```
2d_array=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,56,7,1]])
for elem in 2d_array:
    print(elem[elem[:]>2])
```

Output:

```
[3 4]
[ 4 56  7]
```

Can we do the same without using a `for loop`, Preferably using `numpy` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy produces arrays. In your case, each resulting line has a different length, so you can't get an array, just a list of lists.

However, if you want to gather all the values into a 1D array, you can just do

```
vaulues = array_2d[array_2d > 2]
```